# Difference between env/bin/python and env/lib/pythonX.Y (note the lib)

Tags: python, linux, pip

Sorry for the noob question - just trying to understand the flow of how python works.

Does anyone know what the difference between env/bin/python and env/lib/python3.6 is? It will be really helpful to know. (Note the different paths - bin and lib)

Thanks :)

EDIT: I only have one version of python installed in the environment. The one thing to notice here is that env/bin/python has a symbolic link to env/bin/python3.6 (which is a binary file, obviously). But there is a directory in env/lib/python3.6 in which there are directories like site-packages where the installed packages are stored.

So my questions is... when is the binary file in /env/bin used and when is the directory accessed? When I say 'python' in the shell, it goes to the bin but when I say 'import django' in the interpreter, it goes to python3.6 in lib and gets the package. Am i on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/bin/python is the binary, the program that interprets python code; lib/pythonX.Y is the library that the program uses. The library is a collection of modules and packages written in C/C++ and Python.

lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages is a directory for 3rd-party modules; distutils/setuptools/pip install packages there.

Everything else in lib/pythonX.Y outside of site-packages is the standard library — modules that are always installed with python. The pages at https://docs.python.org/3/ document the standard library but not 3rd-party modules.

Comment: Does the relative path between the two have to be ../lib/pythonX.Y?

Comment: Usually yes though it could be changed.

Answer (score 1):

X and Y represents the version of python you are using.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear... i meant to ask why env/bin and env/lib

Answer (score 0):

Your machine can store multiple versions of python simultaneously, and which one is used depends on the PATH of your current terminal, or if you have a virtual environment set up and activated. You can tell which python interpreter is being used by typing the command

```
> which python
```

If you have both python 2.7 and python 3 installed, you might also be able to choose one by using the full name in terminal

```
> python my_script.py # run using the default python interpreter
> python3 my_script.py # run using the configured version of python3
```

You can find some additional resources in the [official Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) that might help you learn about which version to use and why.

Comment: hey, i only have one version of python installed in the environment. The one thing to notice here is that /env/bin/python is a symbolic link to env/bin/python3.6 (which is a binary file, obviously). But there is a directory in env/lib/python3.6 in which there are dirs like site-packages where the installed packages are stored. So when is the binary file in /env/bin used and when is the dir accessed?